# jquery 3 checkbox. Want to determine which of the checkboxes is clicked

Tags: jquery

jquery 3 checkbox. Want to determine which of the checkboxes is clicked.

Here placed example http://jsfiddle.net/ry5p6/

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mark[]" id="mark1" class="mark" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="mark[]" id="mark2" class="mark" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="mark[]" id="mark2" class="mark" value="3">
```

jquery

```
$('.mark').click(function(index){

alert (index);
if ( $(this).is(":checked") ){
alert ( $(this).val() + ' if checked' );
}

$(this).click(function() {
alert ( $(this).val() + ' click' );
}); 


})//$('.mark').click(function(index){
```

I want `alert (index);` alert number of clicked button but get `[object Object]`

Comment: look at the [:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector

Comment: Note that the *index* in `.click(function(index)` does not actually return the *index*, but the click event object is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
$(this).index();//or $(this).index()+1; for index starting from 0
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A96jZ/)**

*Note: index() is zero index based.*

Answer (score 1):

Get index use

```
 $('.mark').click(function(){
     $('.mark:checked').each(function(){
     alert( $('.mark').index(this));
    });

});
```

### [Updaated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ry5p6/4/)

Answer (score 1):

use `.index()`:

```
 $('.mark').click(function(index){
    alert($(this).index() +1);
 });
```

as `.index()` is `0` based so if you are looking for `1` based then you can intialise its value with `+1`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have `index` parameter in function for `click` event, this is available when you call `.each()`

You can call `.index()` on clicked checkbox object to get index, like below :

```
$('.mark').click(function(){
  var index = $(this).index();
  alert(index);
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ry5p6/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('.mark').click(function(){

alert ($(this).index());
if ( $(this).is(":checked") ){
alert ( $(this).val() + ' if checked' );
}

$(this).click(function() {
alert ( $(this).val() + ' click' );
}); 


})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cLDaT/